# Alignment issues with div inside div

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a progress bar and i have a problem aligning div inside a div.

css:

```
.outer {
width: 20px;
height: 190px;
border: 2px solid #ccc;
overflow: hidden;
position: relative;
-moz-border-radius: 4px;
-webkit-border-radius: 4px;
border-radius: 4px;
display:inline-block;
}

.inner {
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    border-top-width: 0;
    background-image: url('/images/progressBar2Red.png');
    background-size: 20px;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 0%;
    display:inline-block;
}
.progress{
    display: inline-block;
    align-items:center;
}
```

html:

```
<div class="progress">
   <label class="progNum">20</label><br />
   <div class="outer"> 
     <div class="inner"></div>
   </div>
</div>
```

For some reason the inner div is not exactly in the middle of the outer div. This is how it looks:
[image]

How can i put the inner div exactly in the middle of the outer div?

Comment: `align-items:center;` isn't this flexbox only?

Comment: Also, don't use `<br />` for layout.

Comment: Send a live link to this script, I have used your CSS and HTML and it works just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You made this `.inner` element of `position: absolute`. Just add `left: 0;` and `right: 0;` to the `.inner` `CSS` rules.

Divs are of 100% width by default, never set a div to a 100% width unless you absolutely need it... for some reason.

**EDIT**

Ok I actually do not understand what DOES NOT work for you. Check this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YnVLj/). I think the problem is your background.

Comment: Its a part of a more complex page. Adding right: 0; and left: 0; solved the problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Give the inner `margin: 0 auto;`

Answer (score 0):

[**JSfiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/D3qLf/1/)

**HTML**

```
<div class="progress">
   <label class="progNum">20</label>
   <div class="outer"> 
     <div class="inner"></div>
   </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.outer {
height: 190px;
border: 2px solid #ccc;
overflow: hidden;
position: relative;
border-radius: 4px;
}

.inner {
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    border-top-width: 0;
    background-color: red;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height:20px; /* or anything else you want */
    border-radius: 4px;
}
.progress{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 20px; /* sets width of the whole bar - everything else can be 100% */
}

.progNum {
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
}
```